# How to matching string in multilines in Python?

Tags: python, string, matching

I got a logic problem about matching strings in multilines. anyone can help.

The goal is to match the word in search_sentence to the sentence in every line.

```
search_sentence = "for learning distinctive features among"

raw_sentences = ["methods it is possible to among recognize Instagram filters and at-", # 01
                 "tenuate the sensor pattern noise signal in images. Amerini", # 02
                 "et al. [10] introduced a CNN for learning distinctive features", # 03
                 "among social networks. for learning distinctive features among from the histogram of the discrete co-", # 04
                 "sine transform (DCT) coefficients and the noise residual of", # 05
                 "the images. Phan et al. [11] proposed a method to track mul-", # 06
                 "tiple image sharing on social networks by using a CNN for ar-", # 07
                 "chitecture able to learn", # 08
                 "et al. [10] introduced a CNN for learning distinctive features among it is possible to among recognize Instagram filters", # 09
                 "and at- tenuate xx"] # 10


def longest_intersection(string1, string2):
    list1 = string1.split()
    list2 = string2.split()
    intersection = []
    for word in list1:
        if word in list2 and word == list2[0]:
            intersection.append(word)
            list2.remove(word)
    if " ".join(intersection) in search_sentence:
        return intersection


for line in raw_sentences:


    one_line_match = ' '.join(longest_intersection(line.strip(), search_sentence))


    if one_line_match != "" and one_line_match[0] == search_sentence[0]:
        print(one_line_match)
        search_sentence = search_sentence.replace(one_line_match, "").strip()
        if search_sentence == "":
            search_sentence = "for learning distinctive features among"
    else:
        print("[no matched sentences!]")
        search_sentence = "for learning distinctive features among"
```

for now, my outputs are:

[no matched sentences!]
[no matched sentences!]
for learning distinctive features
among
[no matched sentences!]
[no matched sentences!]
for
[no matched sentences!]
for learning distinctive features among
[no matched sentences!]

```
but I desired output will be like this:

[no matched sentences!]
[no matched sentences!]
for learning distinctive features
among for learning distinctive features among
[no matched sentences!]
[no matched sentences!]
[no matched sentences!]
[no matched sentences!]
for learning distinctive features among
[no matched sentences!]
```

Comment: my goal is matching a sentence in a paragraph. the sentences in the paragraph will be in multilines,usually a line will be a part of a sentence. for example:

search_str = "I have a pen"

paragraph can be like:

My name is XXX. I have # 01
a pen which I like it. # 02
Because I have a pen. So I #03
can have a pen pen. # 04
I have a pen. I have a pen xxx. # 05

the desired ouput is:
I have
a pen
I have a pen
[nothing...]
I have a pen I have a pen

Comment: Just rewrite my comment with corrections : first you match the "for" alone line 7, and second you have to check that you looked all words in the line before going to the next line. Seems like all is turning around going to the end of the line with more checks before printing something.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will be try it

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work for solution. I use regex module to search in a sentence. (search_sentence in a raw_sentence)

```
import re
search_sentence = "for learning distinctive features among"
raw_sentences = ["methods it is possible to among recognize Instagram filters and at-", # 01
                 "tenuate the sensor pattern noise signal in images. Amerini", # 02
                 "et al. [10] introduced a CNN for learning distinctive features", # 03
                 "among social networks. for learning distinctive features among from the histogram of the discrete co-", # 04
                 "sine transform (DCT) coefficients and the noise residual of", # 05
                 "the images. Phan et al. [11] proposed a method to track mul-", # 06
                 "tiple image sharing on social networks by using a CNN for ar-", # 07
                 "chitecture able to learn", # 08
                 "et al. [10] introduced a CNN for learning distinctive features among it is possible to among recognize Instagram filters", # 09
                 "and at- tenuate xx"] # 10

for sentence in raw_sentences:
    result = re.findall(f'\s+({search_sentence})\s+', sentence, re.IGNORECASE)
    if len(result) > 0:
        print(result[0])
    else:
        print('no matched sentences!')
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. it seem like can only detect the pattern which same with the search sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Based on initial code, here is a better solution (but not the best) with 3 more limit cases :

```
search_sentence = "for learning distinctive features among"
initial_sentence = "for learning distinctive features among"

raw_sentences = ["methods it is possible to among recognize Instagram filters and at-", # 01
                 "tenuate the sensor pattern noise signal in images. Amerini", # 02
                 "et al. [10] introduced a CNN for learning distinctive features", # 03
                 "among social networks. for learning distinctive features among from the histogram of the discrete co-", # 04
                 "sine transform (DCT) coefficients and the noise residual of", # 05
                 "the images. Phan et al. [11] proposed a method to track mul-", # 06
                 "tiple image sharing on social networks by using a CNN for ar-", # 07
                 "chitecture able to learn", # 08
                 "et al. [10] introduced a CNN for learning distinctive features among it is possible to among recognize Instagram filters", # 09
                 "and at- tenuate xx", # 10
                 "for learning", # 11
                 "distinctive", # 12
                 "features among", # 13
                 "for learning TEST distinctive features among", # 14
                 "for learning distinctive features among for learning distinctive features among", # 15
                 "for learning"] # 16

def longest_intersection(string1, string2):
    list1 = string1.split()
    list2 = string2.split()
    intersection = []
    index = 0
    for word in list1:
        if index == len(list2):
            index = 0
            if len(list2) != len(initial_sentence):
                list2 = initial_sentence.split()
        if word == list2[index]:
            intersection.append(word)
            index = index + 1
        else:
            if intersection == []:
                continue
            elif intersection[-1] == initial_sentence.split()[-1]:
                continue
            else:
                intersection = []
    return intersection

all_matches = []
for line in raw_sentences:
    one_line_match = ' '.join(longest_intersection(line.strip(), search_sentence))
    if one_line_match != "" and one_line_match[0] == search_sentence[0]:
        all_matches.append(one_line_match)
        search_sentence = search_sentence.replace(one_line_match, "").strip()
        if search_sentence == "":
            search_sentence = "for learning distinctive features among"
    else:
        all_matches.append("[no matched sentences!]")
        search_sentence = "for learning distinctive features among" 

index = 0
for match in all_matches:
    if index == len(all_matches)-1: #last match
        if match.split()[-1] == initial_sentence.split()[-1]:
            print(match)
            break
        else:
            print("[no matched sentences!]")
            break
    print(match)
    index = index +1
```

with the result :

```
[no matched sentences!]
[no matched sentences!]
for learning distinctive features
among for learning distinctive features among
[no matched sentences!]
[no matched sentences!]
[no matched sentences!]
[no matched sentences!]
for learning distinctive features among
[no matched sentences!]
for learning
distinctive
features among
[no matched sentences!]
for learning distinctive features among for learning distinctive features among
[no matched sentences!]
```